# C# console calling SQL - bad execution while string contains lithuanian letters

Tags: c#, sql, string, console, letters

My C# Console Applcation:

1:

```
string CE_ParentName_ = CEReader5[0].ToString(); // get string with lithuanian letters for example "Konsolės".
```

if I use `Console.WriteLine()` , I get correct output in console.

2:

```
readname.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] FROM [Net7].[dbo].[GroupFilter] WHERE 
[GroupFilterName]='" + CE_ParentName_ + "'"; // I need to find records in my DB with name of that string (1 possible option)
```

3:

```
if (NameReader.Read()) { idd = NameReader[0].ToString(); } // if i get any results ar no.2 i need to read them
```

The point is that no.2 returns zero results if string contains lithuanian letters. If string is w/o lithuanian letters - everything works perfect. Tried everything, you are my last hope folks.

Comment: Stop what your doing right now and look into using Parameterized Queries. Not only will it solve your problem, but it'll also take care of the incredibly huge glaring SQL injection vulnerability you have. Start here: http://johnhforrest.com/2010/10/parameterized-sql-queries-in-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are Lithuanian characters multibyte? (like Japanese for example)
Is the GroupFilterName NVARCHAR or VARCHAR? If it's NVARCHAR, perhaps you need to put N in front of the string.

Eg.

```
readname.CommandText = "SELECT [ID] FROM [Net7].[dbo].[GroupFilter] WHERE 
[GroupFilterName]=N'" + CE_ParentName_ + "'";
```

And see asawyer's comment regarding avoiding **injection attacks**.

Comment: Hi, about injection attacks i will re-work program later of course. Thank you about that asawyer. But my program is being run internally at windows server (sheduled tasks) to sinchronize one DB to another. I think i dont have to be afraid of injection or i am not right?

Regarding to user2444499 answer: GroupFilterName - nvarchar(255). Will try you suggestion.

Comment: User2444499 - N in front of string does not help. I would like to mention/repeat that when GroupFilterName - w/o Lithuanian symbols - everything goes ok. Lithuanian charakters is like german/french/polish some special eg. Ą, Č, Ę. I think they are not multibyte.

Comment: Have you tried running the sql query directly in SQL Server Management Studio (assuming you're using SQL Server) to see if it works? I'd try the parameterised queries. Even if your code is an internal application, it's just bad practise the way you are setting the CommandText. It's only a few extra lines of code to used a parametised query.